# find a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^5$ (expressed by the unknowns $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$) that fulfills $T(x) = y$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Info given:**

There is a linear transformation $T$: $\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ given by
$$
  T\left(\begin{array}{r}
\mathbf{x}
\end{array}\right)
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
2x_1-4x_2-x_3-3x_4+2x_5\\
-x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_5\\
x_1-2_x2-x_3-3x_4-x_5\\
-x_1+4x_2-x_3+5x_5
\end{array}\right]
\quad
\text{for}
\quad
\mathbf{x} = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5
\end{array}\right]
\in \mathbb{R}^5
$$

First I've found the matrix $A$ that fulfulls $T(x) = Ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^5$.

After that, I am told that we should let $y = ($$y_1$ $y_2$ $y_3$ $y_4$)$^T$ $\in \mathbb{R}^4$ be an arbitrary (but unknown) vector.

**Question/task:**

My task is then to find a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^5$ (expressed by the unknowns $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4$) that fulfills  $T(x) = y$

**My try:**

I have tried myself and end up with the following:
$$x = \frac{y}{A}$$

$$=
\frac{\left(\begin{matrix}
y_1  \\
y_2  \\
y_3 \\
y_4 
\end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & -4 & -1 & -3 & 2  \\
-1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -1 \\
-1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & 1 
\end{matrix}\right)}$$

$$=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{y_1}{2-4-1-3+2}  \\
\frac{y_2}{-1+2+1+1}  \\
\frac{y_3}{1-2-1-3-1} \\
\frac{y_4}{-1+4-1+1}
\end{matrix}\right)$$

I'm not sure if this is correct or if the approach is correct. Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Dividing by a matrix? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, but $x = \frac{y}{A}$ is non-sense !

To find $x$, you have to solve the linear system $Ax=y$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: So glad I asked here first! Thanks, Fred

Comment: Fred do you mind show me your approach then? I am lost at this.

Comment: Can this answer be corret? 

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
2*y-11*x_5 \\
y-4*x_5 \\
y-4*x_5 \\
\frac{-2*y}{3} \\
x_5
\end{matrix}\right)$$